# minecraft 1.8.7 slow fps on i7 , but very fast if i run furemark

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Processor I7 2630qm, and I have installed Minecraft 1.8.7 on Windows 7,  java 1.7.0-45-b18, I see 20 FPS when I run the game. If I run furemark benchmark's cpu burner on 1 thread, and I play Minecraft at the same time, Minecraft shows 120 FPS. my video card is amd radeon 6490m I play on a laptop.
It seems that the benchmark program is able to make the processor to go fast, but Minecraft is not.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Disable power savings mode in the configuration application of your graphics card.

Comment: Can you confirm that the game runs on the dedicated video card instead of integrated one?

Comment: thanks. i confirm power saving mode is disabled, and i confirm the video card active is the radeon one and not the integrated one.

Comment: Try going to the Minecraft/Java process and setting it to a higher priority.

Comment: 1. It's spelled Furnmark. 2. Just because it's an i7, doesn't mean its fast. An i7-U has only 2 cores, 4 threads, at a lower clock speed than a normal HQ, T, or K Processor, with 4 cores, 8 Threads.

Answer (score -1):

Check all these things first:
-Is your laptop pugged in to the charger?
-Are your power settings set to high performance?
-Do you have the most recent version of Java?
-Do you have the most recent version of your video card driver?

If these are all true and your FPS is still low:
-Try a less recent video card driver (1 version prior)
-If this doesn't work, update back to the most recent
-Try to change(lower) your rendering distance. 12 is normal, 9 is doable.
-Try to make use of optifine
-Try to "play" with your video settings to find the settings that alters the FPS the most